# Plivo SIP problems with NAT traversal

Tags: networking, nat, voip, sip

Ok, I've looked and looked, and can't seem to find anyone that's written about this problem. I have a simple office setup where there are two SIP phone extensions (Polycom 331) behind a Sonicwall TZ180. I'm using Plivo as the PBX. The extensions register directly with Plivo.

```
Plivo --> [Internet] --> TimeWarner Modem --> Sonicwall TZ180 --> POE Switch --> Polycom 331s x2
```

I've setup the firewall & NAT rules on the TZ180 such that everything works... for a while. After the sonicwall & phones are rebooted, the phones can both receive and make calls without issue. Once some time has passed (not sure how much, but more than a few hours, may even be a few days), the phones stop accepting INCOMING calls, but outgoing calls are fine.

So, to me this seems like a NAT issue, except for the part where everything works fine for awhile! And I really do mean it works fine. Call phone 1, talk for a bit, then call phone 2, talk for a bit, call phone 1 again, talk for a bit, call phone 2, talk for a bit, repeat. But then, after some unknown amount of time with no calls, the above ceases to work for both phones.

The Sonicwall firewall is set to pass `UDP 5060-5061` and `UDP/TCP 10000-20000`. The phones are provided with static private IPs by the Sonicwall. The Sonicwall's consistent NAT is enables, and SIP transformations are disabled (which seems to be the consensus I found elsewhere).

Any ideas? The only way we can seem to detect that the phones have stopped working for incoming calls is to wait until a voicemail is delivered, but someone was sitting next to the phone. Also, I'd rather not have to reboot my entire network just to get another day or two each time.

Comment: Do you have a spare public IP address?  If so, assign it to one of the phones and plug it directly into the TW modem, bypassing the Sonicwall and see if the same issue happens.
Getting packet captures from both working and not working examples would help as well.

Comment: I'll see if I can do that tomorrow. Not sure about the public IP addresses though, as it's on a residential-grade connection. I think they allow multiple dynamic public addresses. I can always move the POE switch to sitting between the TWC & Sonicwall.

Comment: Is the modem doing NAT?   When the problem happens, can you make outgoing calls?

Comment: No NAT on the modem (so no double nat), the WAN IP of the Sonicwall is publicly reachable. Also, yes, the outgoing call function seems to always work, even when the incoming function fails.

Comment: So no one-way audio issues on outgoing calls?  
Have you checked the Sonicwall logs to see if it is blocking traffic from Plivo?

Comment: Just got confirmation from the people who use the phones, they confirm that the outgoing calls work perfectly - no audio issues. Occasionally there will be only silence after dialing, but hanging up and redialing fixes that.

RE Logs: I've checked them, and they weren't helpful to me at the time. Unfortunately I didn't keep them (and in the Sonicwall I have to set it to debug when the problem is occurring to capture everything, but didn't think to do that this time - and it's currently working).

Comment: Packet captures would be the best way to troubleshoot, preferably outside the Sonicwall.  Without more information not much more I can say at the moment.

Comment: I'll try to get a laptop with wireshark over there tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after struggling with wireshark, I've essentially discovered that the Sonicwall TZ180, being as old as it is, just doesn't like holding multiple NAT paths open. I've solved the problem with a Raspberry Pi running asterisk and acting as a SIP Proxy.